# How do I simplify this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a way to simplify this integral:

```
Integrate[Exp[I*(a*p + b*q)]*Boole[p^2 + q^2 < r^2], {p, -r, r}, {q, -r, r}]
```

Comment: It will probably help to change variables to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you integrate over the appropriate region then Mathematica can do the integral

```
Integrate[Exp[I*(a*p + b*q)], Element[{p, q}, Disk[{0, 0}, r]]]
```

Returns:

```
ConditionalExpression[
   Pi r^2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -(1/4) (a^2 + b^2) r^2], 
   r > 0 && (Im[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]] > 0 || Re[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]] > 0)
]
```

---

This is the same result you get if you make the change to polar coordinates suggested in the first comment to your question: 
$(p,q)=R (\cos(\theta), R \sin(\theta))$

```
Integrate[R Exp[I R (a Cos[theta] + b Sin[theta])] , 
          {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {R, 0, r}, 
          Assumptions -> r > 0 && Element[a | b, Reals]]
```

Returns

```
Pi r^2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -(1/4) (a^2 + b^2) r^2]
```

Comment: `Assuming[
 Element[{a, b}, Reals] && (Abs[a] > 0 || Abs[b] > 0) && r > 0, 
   Integrate[
       Exp[I*(a*p + b*q)], 
       Element[{p, q}, Disk[{0, 0}, 
           r]]] // FunctionExpand]` evaluates to `(2*Pi*r*BesselJ[1, Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]*r])/
   Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, thanks! I was wondering though, why do we get a different form when we use Element[{p, q}, Disk[{0, 0}, r] instead? Also, I don't get the function of Assuming[] here.

Comment: @Navya - The `Hypergeometric0F1Regularized` expression can be converted to the equivalent `BesselJ` expression with `FunctionExpand`. It is just a matter of taste as to which form is preferred. The `Assuming` eliminates the conditions of an conditional expression by essentially saying that all of the required conditions are met.